# CSS: nested list - how to highlight entire line?

Tags: css, html-lists, nested-lists

I have a nested list like this :

```
   <ul class="tree">
     <li><div>Animals</div>
       <ul>
         <li><div>Birds</div>
           <ul>
             <li class="last"><div>Eagle</div></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><div>Mammals</div>
           <ul>
             <li><div>Elephant</div></li>
             <li class="last"><div>Cats</div>
               <ul>
                 <li><div>Lion</div></li>
                 <li class="last"><div>Tiger</div></li>
               </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="last"><div>Reptiles</div>
           <ul>
             <li><div>Snake</li>
             <li class="last"><div>Turtle</div></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
```

I'd like to style this so each level is indented, but I also wish to have each *entire* line highlighted when hovered. When I put a hover on `DIV` , the highlighting only starts from the left-position of the containing `UL`:

```
  ul.tree, ul.tree ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  ul.tree li div:hover {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

Is there some way to achieve the effect I want, without defining multiple rules for `li li`, `li li li`, etc. ? 
There could be an infinite number of levels of nesting, so I find it quite ugly to define all these different rules.

Or is there a way to calculate the level of nesting dynamically (in CSS?), so I could remove the padding of `UL` and instead put the right amount of padding inside each `DIV` ?

***UPDATE:***

added a fiddle that shows what I want:  http://jsfiddle.net/za3db/

You can see it's only indented on the second level, because I did not define the rule for the third, or fourth...

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle that better displays what you mean by "the entire line"?

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a *tad* late, however I was working on a tree recently and had the exact same thought and found a solution by studying the way several products tackle it. The below snippet illustrates a possible solution by placing a **fill** `div` for each item in the tree which has a large negative margin which allows it to cover the whole line. It's a very simple `CSS` only solution.

Hopefully it will help you and others who come across this question + answer.

```css
.fill {
  display: none;
  margin-left: -10000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
}

.title:hover .fill {
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tree">
  <li>
    <div class="title">
      <div class="fill"></div>
      Animals
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="title">
          <div class="fill"></div>
          Birds
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li class="last">
            <div class="title">
              <div class="fill"></div>
              Eagle
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="title">
          <div class="fill"></div>
          Mammals
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="title">
              <div class="fill"></div>
              Elephant
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="last">
            <div class="title">
              <div class="fill"></div>
              Cats
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div class="title">
                  <div class="fill"></div>
                  Lion
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="last">
                <div class="title">
                  <div class="fill"></div>
                  Tiger
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="last">
        <div class="title">
          <div class="fill"></div>
          Reptiles
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="title">
              <div class="fill"></div>
              Snake
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="last">
            <div class="title">
              <div class="fill"></div>
              Turtle
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to do it with CSS, but it can be done with a little bit of javascript (jQuery).

```
$(".tree div").each(function()
{
    var padding = $(this).parents("ol, ul").length * 20 + "px";

    $(this).css("padding-left", padding);
});
```

[See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za3db/3/)

Comment: Thank you, this looks very clean and simple. The only 'problem' is that I discovered that to nicely display hierarchy lines (like in Windows Explorer on XP) the UL's need to be indented. But I admit, I did not mention this in my question.

Comment: @Dylan I have similar issue thing looking for, did u solve it with css this by any chance ?

Comment: @jsduniya, I posted an answer yesterday which I think will help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68268012/771466

Answer (score 0):

This kinda does was you want: http://jsfiddle.net/za3db/4/

It is placing an absolute positioned (`left:0; right:0`) pseudo-element under (`z-index:-1`) each of your `div`s. But this construct has 2 downsides:

- It only works when you know the height of the div (in my example always `1.3em` = line-height)
- It wont highlight when you hover over the indent, because the div still doesnt start at the left.

So the best solution might still be javascript or just writing down all those `li li`, `li li li`, ... rules.

---

Edit: I played a little more with it and came up with a new version using hidden floated `counter()`-pseudo-elements for the indent: http://jsfiddle.net/za3db/5/.

Comment: Thanks for you effort, this looks very promising. Any idea if it also works on IE8 (since jsfiddle.net does not seem to work on IE8) ?

Comment: One slight problem: elements that are too long wrap to the next line and are not indented anymore. I fixed this with adding some white-space: nowrap; , but because of the overflow: hidden; no horizontal scrollbar is displayed, so the rest of the element disappears out of sight... but with overflow set on auto, it gets VERY wide because of the 10000 pixel padding and margin...